# Ember : How can i create routes and controllers at runtime?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have to dynamically create routes and controllers based on the parameters i receive at run time. I cannot create routes beforehand because there are simply too many routes that use the same code with minor differences. Is this possible? If so, how?

The problem I a trying to solve :
 My application has a tabbed ui with routing. That is, each tab points to a new route. I have divided my modules into different routes. Each route has its own controller and so on. Now the issue is, each module can act differently according to the configuration that I receive from the database. Users need to be able to open the same module in different tabs but this is not possible because one route represents a module and since controllers are singleton, two instances of the same module cannot exist simultaneously.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve this way? This doesn't sound like the right solution to any problem. :)

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my question to describe the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Routable components was an approach I looked at, but again, each module is a route. So I can't open the same module twice.

Comment: Have you considered to build everything with components and don't use the router at all? if you have multiple tabs, what should show up in your url?

Comment: Could you elaborate why using dynamic route segments is not possible? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted my modules (which were previously hosted on separate routes) to components and then used a tabbing construct to open each module on a click action in a separate tab. In this scenario since each module is a component  i was able to open multiple instances of the same module.